# Why won't R plot all the values of my dataframe and why won't it connect the dots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a molten dataframe (df.long1) containing two variables (v07, v08). While the code plots the first variable (v07) through geom_point, it won't connect the points with geom_line.

```
df.long1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.numeric(year), value, label = value))+
  geom_line(size = 1.5, alpha = 0.8)+
  geom_point(size = 5, alpha = 0.5)+
  ylim(0,70)+
  labs(x = "",
       y="")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(text = element_text(myfont),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=0.5))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text=element_text(size=16, color = "black"))+
  geom_text(hjust=0.2, vjust=-1.5, size = 5.5)+
  scale_color_manual(values=palette(rexcol),
                     labels = mynames)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000:2021))
```

[image: plot]

At the same time, the second variable won't be plotted at all plus I am getting this message:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 1 row containing missing values (`geom_line()`). 
2: Removed 20 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`). 
3: Removed 20 rows containing missing values (`geom_text()`).
```

But if I am plotting v08 like this, I am getting exactly what I want:

```
v08 %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.numeric(year), v08, label = v08))+
  geom_line(size = 1.5, alpha = 0.8)+
  geom_point(size = 5, alpha = 0.5)
```

[image: plot2]

This is the df.long1 Dataframe:

```
df.long1
# A tibble: 40 × 3
   year  type  value
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 2001  v07      48
 2 2001  v08      83
 3 2002  v07      40
 4 2002  v08      79
 5 2003  v07      37
 6 2003  v08      79
 7 2004  v07      50
 8 2004  v08      80
 9 2005  v07      37
10 2005  v08      79
```

Comment: Use `coord_cartesian(ylim = ...)` to "zoom into" the plot. `ylim` removes data that is outside the limits.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `group` aesthetics like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df.long1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.numeric(year), value, label = value))+
  geom_line(aes(group = type), size = 1.5, alpha = 0.8)+
  geom_point(size = 5, alpha = 0.5)+
  ylim(0,70)+
  labs(x = "",
       y="")+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.text=element_text(size=16, color = "black"))+
  geom_text(hjust=0.2, vjust=-1.5, size = 5.5)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000:2021))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It worked! Could you elaborate on why it would only work with the group aes?

Comment: Hi @xnhZZZ, with the group aesthetic you could group certain points and/or lines based on a variable. Check [this](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html) for more info.